# dmraid don't activate disk

Tags: dmraid

Background : this trouble appears after an upgrade from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. My /home partition was on my Ubunutu 16.04 a raid 5 partition from 3 disk, manage with lvm2. I have absolutly no trouble.
After upgrade with command "do-release-upgrade" from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, the first reboot failed. I send a first message on this trouble :
[Trouble after upgrade 16.04 -> 18.04 - device mapper?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1223094/trouble-after-upgrade-16-04-18-04-device-mapper)
Now, it's more clear about my comprehension of trouble.

Actually, I have disactivate use of raid disk, by editing /etc/fstab and comment mounting point of /home . So now I have a starting server under Ubuntu 18.04, without any data from my raid disks.

So now, I try to recover data that are on my 3 disks, previously use in RAID 5.

So now, I try :

```
root@xxx:~# dmraid -s
*** Group superset isw_eaabdhefe
--> Subset
name   : isw_eaabdhefe_raid5
size   : 7814048256
stride : 256
type   : raid5_la
status : ok
subsets: 0
devs   : 3
spares : 0
root@xxx:~#  dmraid -r
/dev/sdc: isw, "isw_eaabdhefe", GROUP, ok, 3907029166 sectors, data@ 0
/dev/sde: isw, "isw_eaabdhefe", GROUP, ok, 3907029166 sectors, data@ 0
/dev/sdd: isw, "isw_eaabdhefe", GROUP, ok, 3907029166 sectors, data@ 0
root@xxx:~#
```

So according most of documentation, I'm ready to activate raid group with :

```
root@xxx:~# dmraid -ay
RAID set "isw_eaabdhefe_raid5" was not activated
root@xxx:~#
```

more precise

```
root@xxx:~# dmraid -tay
isw_eaabdhefe_raid5: 0 7814048256 raid raid5_la 4 256 nosync region_size 131072 3 - /dev/sdc - /dev/sdd - /dev/sde
root@xxx:~#
```

Each time I try to activate, I have theses lines in dmesg :

```
[xxx] device-mapper: table: 253:0: raid: RAID device lookup failure
[xxx] device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
```

I have also try :

```
root@xxx:~# dmraid -ay -vvv -d
WARN: locking /var/lock/dmraid/.lock
NOTICE: /dev/sda: asr     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sda: ddf1    discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sda: hpt37x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sda: hpt45x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sda: isw     discovering
DEBUG: not isw at 180045765632
DEBUG: isw trying hard coded -2115 offset.
DEBUG: not isw at 180044683776
NOTICE: /dev/sda: jmicron discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sda: lsi     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sda: nvidia  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sda: pdc     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sda: sil     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sda: via     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdc: asr     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdc: ddf1    discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdc: hpt37x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdc: hpt45x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdc: isw     discovering
DEBUG: isw metadata found at 2000398932992 from probe at 2000398932992

NOTICE: /dev/sdc: isw metadata discovered
NOTICE: /dev/sdc: jmicron discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdc: lsi     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdc: nvidia  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdc: pdc     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdc: sil     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdc: via     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sde: asr     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sde: ddf1    discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sde: hpt37x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sde: hpt45x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sde: isw     discovering
DEBUG: isw metadata found at 2000398932992 from probe at 2000398932992

NOTICE: /dev/sde: isw metadata discovered
NOTICE: /dev/sde: jmicron discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sde: lsi     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sde: nvidia  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sde: pdc     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sde: sil     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sde: via     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdb: asr     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdb: ddf1    discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdb: hpt37x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdb: hpt45x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdb: isw     discovering
DEBUG: not isw at 160041884672
DEBUG: isw trying hard coded -2115 offset.
DEBUG: not isw at 160040802816
NOTICE: /dev/sdb: jmicron discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdb: lsi     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdb: nvidia  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdb: pdc     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdb: sil     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdb: via     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdd: asr     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdd: ddf1    discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdd: hpt37x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdd: hpt45x  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdd: isw     discovering
DEBUG: isw metadata found at 2000398932992 from probe at 2000398932992

NOTICE: /dev/sdd: isw metadata discovered
NOTICE: /dev/sdd: jmicron discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdd: lsi     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdd: nvidia  discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdd: pdc     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdd: sil     discovering
NOTICE: /dev/sdd: via     discovering
DEBUG: _find_set: searching isw_eaabdhefe
DEBUG: _find_set: not found isw_eaabdhefe
DEBUG: _find_set: searching isw_eaabdhefe_raid5
DEBUG: _find_set: searching isw_eaabdhefe_raid5
DEBUG: _find_set: not found isw_eaabdhefe_raid5
DEBUG: _find_set: not found isw_eaabdhefe_raid5
NOTICE: added /dev/sdc to RAID set "isw_eaabdhefe"
DEBUG: _find_set: searching isw_eaabdhefe
DEBUG: _find_set: found isw_eaabdhefe
DEBUG: _find_set: searching isw_eaabdhefe_raid5
DEBUG: _find_set: searching isw_eaabdhefe_raid5
DEBUG: _find_set: found isw_eaabdhefe_raid5
DEBUG: _find_set: found isw_eaabdhefe_raid5
NOTICE: added /dev/sde to RAID set "isw_eaabdhefe"
DEBUG: _find_set: searching isw_eaabdhefe
DEBUG: _find_set: found isw_eaabdhefe
DEBUG: _find_set: searching isw_eaabdhefe_raid5
DEBUG: _find_set: searching isw_eaabdhefe_raid5
DEBUG: _find_set: found isw_eaabdhefe_raid5
DEBUG: _find_set: found isw_eaabdhefe_raid5
NOTICE: added /dev/sdd to RAID set "isw_eaabdhefe"
DEBUG: set status of set "isw_eaabdhefe_raid5" to 16
DEBUG: dm_raid: low level dev /dev/sdc
DEBUG: dm_raid: low level dev /dev/sdd
DEBUG: dm_raid: low level dev /dev/sde
RAID set "isw_eaabdhefe_raid5" was not activated
INFO: Activating GROUP raid set "isw_eaabdhefe"
WARN: unlocking /var/lock/dmraid/.lock
DEBUG: freeing devices of RAID set "isw_eaabdhefe_raid5"
DEBUG: freeing device "isw_eaabdhefe_raid5", path "/dev/sdc"
DEBUG: freeing device "isw_eaabdhefe_raid5", path "/dev/sdd"
DEBUG: freeing device "isw_eaabdhefe_raid5", path "/dev/sde"
DEBUG: freeing devices of RAID set "isw_eaabdhefe"
DEBUG: freeing device "isw_eaabdhefe", path "/dev/sdc"
DEBUG: freeing device "isw_eaabdhefe", path "/dev/sdd"
DEBUG: freeing device "isw_eaabdhefe", path "/dev/sde"
root@xxx:~#
```

Can anybody help me to understand theses lines ?

more information :

```
root@xxx:~# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) (rev 05)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C204 Chipset LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. MGA G200e [Pilot] ServerEngines (SEP1) (rev 07)
root@xxx:~#
```

```
root@xxx:~# ls -al /dev/mapper/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root      60 avril  1 12:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root    4340 avril  1 17:33 ..
crw-------  1 root root 10, 236 avril  1 12:30 control
root@xxx:~#
```

```
root@xxx:~# cat /proc/partitions 
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0  175825944 sda
   8        1     975872 sda1
   8        2  174848000 sda2
   8       16  156290904 sdb
   8       17   31249408 sdb1
   8       18    9765888 sdb2
   8       19    2097152 sdb3
   8       20  113176576 sdb4
   8       64 1953514584 sde
   8       32 1953514584 sdc
   8       48 1953514584 sdd
   9      126 3907023872 md126
root@xxx:~#
```

```
root@xxx:~# dmraid -V
dmraid version:     1.0.0.rc16 (2009.09.16) shared 
dmraid library version: 1.0.0.rc16 (2009.09.16)
device-mapper version:  4.37.0
root@xxx:~#
```

```
root@xxx:~# uname -a
Linux xxx 4.15.0-91-generic #92-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 11:09:48 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@xxx:~#
```

sdc, sdd, sde are disks used for raid volume.

I can send more information, just request.

Comment: Any news on this problem? Having the same issue here.

Comment: No news. I have reinstall my raid with mdadm. I see more document with mdadm rather than mdraid.